# A question regarding existence and uniqueness in IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

> Consider the IVP
>
> $$y'(t)=f(y(t)), \ \ \ \ y(0)=a \in \mathbb{R}$$ $$f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
>
> Which of the following is/are true
>
> $(A)$  There exists a continuous function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the above problem does not have a solution in any nbd of $0$.
>
> $(B)$  The problem has unique solution for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$ when $f$ is Lipschitz continuous
>
> $(C)$ When $f$ is twice continuously differentiable the maximal interval of existence for the above IVP is $\mathbb{R}$
>
> $(D)$ The maximum interval of existence  for the IVP is $\mathbb{R}$ when $f$ is bounded and continuously differentiable.

It is obvious to me that $A \ \& \ B$ are false from traditional existance and uniqueness theorems (viz Picards Theorem). I am not sure about $C \ \& \ D$ and this is really bugging me. Please could anyone shed light on this.

**PS:** Multiple correct options are allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A)   should be answered with the existence theorem of Peano.

B)  is an application of Picard-Lindelöf, it seems you only know about the theorem for differentiable $f$?

C)  classical example $f(y)=y^2$.

D) if $|f(y)|\le M$, then $|y(t)-y(0)|\le M·|t|$ by the mean value theorem of your choice.

---

*Details to D)* By the assumption, local solutions exist everywhere. One has to show that one can continue thoes local solutions to the boundaries of their intervals, as one can restart an initial-value problem whose local solution extends the previous one. As $M$ bounds the derivative of any solution, any solution is Lipschitz-continuous which excludes any poles (and jumps and oscillations). Thus the limit at the boundary of a domain always exist.

To do this more systematically, consider the interval $[−T,T]$ for some (large) $T>0$. Set $b=M⋅T$, then there is a global Lipschitz constant $L$ on the compact set $[−T,T]×[−2b,2b]$. Set $a=\min(\frac1{2L},\frac T2)$. Then the Picard iteration is contractive over every interval $[t_0−a,t_0+a]⊂[−T,T]$ by the local quantified version of the Picard-Lindelöf theorem, which allows to find or piece together a unique solution over $[−T,T]$. As there are no restrictions on $T$, one can extend this to all of $R$.

Comment: So $C$ is false and $D$ is true. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You should be able to justify all your choices, even if that is not asked in  a multiple-choice test. It would help against mind games that are often part of those.

Comment: @LutzL how option D is correct? I mean by which result.

Comment: f may not Lipschitz even if it is bounded

Comment: @neelkanth: Continuously differentiable implies locally Lipschitz. As there can be no poles, any local solution can be infinitely extended.

Comment: But locally lip gives solution locally....please can you suggest how it has no poles?

Comment: In part C $y^{2}$ is also locally lip

Comment: I am confused how can we extant it to whole real line....

Comment: Consider the interval $[-T,T]$. Set $b=M·T$, then there is a global Lipschitz constant $L$ on the compact set $[-T,T]×[-2b,2b]$. Set $a=\min(\frac1{2L}, \frac{T}2)$. Then the Picard iteration is contractive over every interval $[t_0-a,t_0+a]\subset[-T,T]$ by the local quantified version of the Picard-Lindelöf theorem, which allows to find or piece together a unique solution over $[-T,T]$. As there are no restrictions on $T$, one can extend this to all of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: if my d.e is $y'=\sin(y)$ ,$y(0)=1.$Then the the solution should be unique and on whole 4\mathbb{R}.?

Comment: @Upstart: As $f(t,y)=\sin y$ is globally Lipschitz in $y$ with constant $1$, you do not need any extra arguments for global existence. But for $y'=\sin(y^2)$ you would indeed need the boundedness argument.

Comment: still if $f(x,y)=\sin (y)$. The solution part would involve an intermediary step involving $\log(g(y))$. So for proceeding ahead of that step, wouldn't we have to make the assumptionn on $y$ and by default on $x$, which would thus shorten the maximum interval of existence

Comment: @Upstart : The roots of $0=\sin(y)$ are stationary points of the ODE, that is, the give constant solutions. By uniqueness, no other solution reaches a root of $sin(y)$. The separation calculation gives the global solutions without further problems.

Comment: Pardon me, but i didn't understand your statement

Comment: So B and D are correct answer. Can you please confirm. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @StammeringMathematician : Yes, these are the correct statements.